# Too many UIViews? What's the cost, what are the tradeoffs?

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview

**EDIT:**

Imagine that I'm in the business of reimplementing CoreText.

I'd get an NSString here which is an ordered list of code-points, and a set of glyphs there (an NSFont/CTFont) that basically is a list of CGPathRef.

Something in-between is in charge of the layout.

And some kind of environment must provide a CGGraphicContext to render into.

The kind of objects I have to display *are* CGPath. I am worried of creating one UIView for each CGPath! For a block of text, you wouldn't create an UIView for each character-glyph, would you?

---

I have a potentially large set of (tiny) objects to draw at once. In the 1000's. Many will be offscreen until scrolled into view.

One one hand it looks like my best bet would be to create one UIView for each one. The reasons are that:

- with proper tiling I can make sure that the views that are offscreen
  are not even in memory most of the time and brought up to life when
  required
- more importantly, when zooming I want to set each such view's layer contentScale to the zoomFactor such that I still get the full
  precision and not the blurry stair-case

On the other hand I have no idea how the (otherwise perfectly generic) parent view will behave with 1000's of children.
So I am tempted to rethink my code such that the "children" just become an area of the single view.
But then I start thinking of setting that view's layer contentScale and I'm worried about exhausting memory just while zooming: I do not know if the layer machinery is "clever"  enough not to create a huge backing bitmap when most of its contents would be invisible anyway

What to do, oh what to do?

Anyone has any experience they want to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently saw a presentation on a game involving hundreds of sprites implemented as UIViews, mostly image views.  Performance was excellent on both an older and recent generation iPad.  His code is available at https://github.com/bentford/ButtonWars/ , so you may want to test it to see if the performance meets your needs.

There is often an assumption that views are heavyweight, but experience doesn't bear that out.

Answer (score 2):

If most of the objects will *not* be on the screen at any time, it's probably better not to create views for all of those off-screen objects.  You need to intelligently add views for just those objects that are visible, and remove them from the view hierarchy when they go off-screen.  You might be able to use `UICollectionView` to make this easy - it is very well designed, efficient, flexible, and easy to use and customize - but I don't know if it works with zooming.

If you decide to draw everything in one view, with deep zooming, you should look at `CATiledLayer`.  It is designed for zooming in very deeply.  Apple's `MKMapView` uses it under the covers to support scaling its viewport from Earth-sized down to a (relatively) few square meters.

Comment: I had a look at `CATiledLayer`, but I admit being a bit confused about the connection, if any, between `levelOfDetails` and `levelOfDetailsBias` on one hand, and `CALayer.contentScale` on the other ...

Answer (score 1):

If you cant use UICollectionView due to iOS version boundations, and you are intrested in re using views in UIScrollView, than have a look at [this](https://github.com/iVishal/VSScroller.git) class. It is used the same way UITableview is used. Just pass in number of views and it will reuse the views.You can go through readme. Its very straightforward.

Comment: Nice try at a shameless plug :) No this doesn't help me. Let's prentend for the sake of refining the question that each one of my tiny object is a character glyph. It isn't, but close enough. You wouldn't go about drawing an NSString with an UICollection as a glyph layout engine, would you? My objects are way too tiny for this and the overhead would probably kill the project dead in its track.

Comment: `UICollectionView` doesn't care if your objects are tiny. And it can scale to 1000s of objects. So I really don't get your objections based on the information given.

Comment: I have given link to a class which does not use UICollectionView. Its just a simple UIScrollview. And besides if your views are very tiny, you can create a large view which will hold and manage a bunch of your tiny views. Byt this , number of views which you will need pass to the datasource will become 1/numberOftinyViewPerLargeView times.:p .

Comment: @TimothyMoose Really imagine that I'm in the business of reimplementing CoreText. I've got a NSString here which is an ordered list of code-points, and a set of glyphs there (an NSFont/CTFont) that basically is a list of CGPathRef. Something in-between is in charge of the layout. And some kind of environment must provide a CGGraphicContext to render into. The kind of objects I have to display *are* CGPath. I am worried of creating one UIView for each CGPath! For a block of text, you wouldn't create an UIView for each character, would you?